# Add Unique constraint to existing table with large amount of data

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, postgresql-11

I have an existing table with following schema

```
create table event_logs
(
    event_id     integer   not null
        constraint event_logs_event_id_fkey
            references event,
    user_id         integer   not null,
    transaction_type_id   integer   not null
        constraint event_logs_transaction_type_id_fkey
            references transaction_type,
    transaction_timestamp timestamp not null,
    created_at      timestamp with time zone,
    transaction_data      jsonb
);

create index event_created_at_index
    on event_logs (created_at);

create index event_transaction_type_id_index
    on event_logs (transaction_type_id);
```

Basically above table is to store any user transaction for a given online event like joining , chatting, leaving etc. When this table was created we forgot to add unique constraint across these columns - event_id, user_id, transaction_type_id, transaction_timestamp. Now the database has ~13,293,556 rows with a lot of duplicates. I am unable to add Unique constraint because of duplicates and when I try to remove duplicate rows,the query timesout. Can you please suggest how I can add unique constraint to avoid any duplicate transaction logs in future.

I am using PostgreSQL 11.12 database

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! I tried [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9e5108e2aefdd38f67fd5be58e482214)-see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-altertable.html). You can have `NOT VALID` `CHECK` constraints, but not for `UNIQUE` ones. I think you're going to have to write a trigger to do this from now on! Or, you could bite the bullet and do some sort of mass `DELETE` - I'd backup first though - either that or put them into some sort of holding table - 13M records shouldn't be too painful? (*) `NOT VALID` means it will only be enforced into the future!